# Best database setup for dual POS?

Tags: mysql, database, cloud, storage, point-of-sale

I am currently setting up my first POS system and would like some advice on the best database setup for my situation.

1. I have two POS computers that need to have seamless database
   integration between the two of them (when adding a record on the
   one, it should reflect on the other instantly)
2. I would like both computers to store a local updated version of
   the database on their respective HDD's.
3. I would also like to back the database up to some sort of cloud
   storage incase something happens to both PC's.
4. It is imperative that both PC's can communicate with each other
   and update the database even when there is NO network connection. 
   NOTE: Both PC's will be connected to a WIFI router with internet
   access. I'm currently using PHPMyAdmin for the database storage.

I have very limited database knowledge. Would Master-Master replication be the best option for this scenario? If so, what would be the best way to go about it?

Thank you.

Comment: you should have center database that get synchronized by both with their unique db id

Comment: We use PostgreSQL as central database, no synchronisation at all, online access to the DB and we make excellent experiences with this setup.  And yes, we have quite a lot of installations and no network/DB related failures.